# Node server is mandatory to deploy in IIS?

Tags: node.js, angular, iis

I have compiled my code using typescript  and run it in my laptop using node server.

Now when i deploy it in windows IIS server in another machine, do i require node server that machine?

Node is just for development and not for hosting?

Can you clarify my doubts?

Comment: Curious about your tagging. What does this have to do with Angular? and you haven't tagged iis either. What is your question exactly?

Comment: i am compling angular code in typscript and deploying in IIS . I have tagged iis

Comment: If you deploy server side javascript, you need node.js. If only client-side javascript is used, no need for node.js at the server.

Comment: since my angular server side and client side code is working fine in IIS, how can i verify node js already installed in IIS?

Comment: IIS only works as a reverse proxy for your application, https://medium.com/intrinsic/why-should-i-use-a-reverse-proxy-if-node-js-is-production-ready-5a079408b2ca

Comment: i checked my server, i didnt find any glance of node in my IIS, but website is working fine without any issues

Comment: Sounds like you are still not sure of what kind of javascript you have, the client javascript or server javascript. Asuming the tag *angular* means the client-side code then, no, you don't need node.js as your static js files are served by IIS's static file handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES. you need node server in the other machine as well in the machine in which you are deploying the code

As far as I know, if you want to host node.js application, you should firstly install the node.exe and the a build of iisnode.

https://nodejs.org/en/#download

https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode

After installed the IIS nodes, you could set up samples, from the administrative command prompt call %programfiles%\iisnode\setupsamples.bat.

Then you could go to http://localhost/node to see the example.

More details, you could refer to below article:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx

Comment: i checked my server, i didnt find any glance of node in my IIS, but website is working fine without any issues

Comment: I haven't used iis server till now.I just read an article about that.Thats it.